# closed geodesics are dense in both hyperbolic surface and unit tangent bundle of hyperbolic surface

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Could you please recommend me some references for proofs of this fact: "closed geodesics are dense in both hyperbolic surface and unit tangent bundle of hyperbolic surface". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper? Thanks

Comment: I converted two comments into an answer, so that the question can be considered as "answered".

Answer (score 7):

See the paper MR1763264 by Marcos Salvai. [Here](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~salvai/cerraddp.pdf) is a link to the paper.